# Finding all the orders who did not have at least one item labeled Confections

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to use a subquery in order to find all the orders that didn't have at least one item in confections. I'm having a hard time with subqueries so any help would be appreciated. This is what I have so far.

```
SELECT O.orderid, O.orderdate, C.custid, C.companyname
FROM Sales.Orders AS O JOIN Sales.Customers AS C ON O.custid = C.custid
JOIN Sales.OrderDetails AS D ON D.orderid = O.orderid
JOIN Production.Products AS P ON P.productid = D.productid
WHERE EXISTS
 (SELECT P.productid FROM Production.Products AS P JOIN 
Production.Categories AS CA
        ON P.categoryid = CA.categoryid JOIN Sales.OrderDetails AS D ON 
        D.orderid = O.orderid
        WHERE CA.categoryname NOT LIKE '%Confections%')
```

Comment: Could you provide some smaple data and expect result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `LEFT JOIN` and `WHERE`:

```
SELECT O.orderid, O.orderdate, C.custid, C.companyname
FROM Sales.Orders O JOIN
     Sales.Customers C
     ON O.custid = C.custid JOIN
     Sales.OrderDetails D 
     ON D.orderid = O.orderid JOIN
     Production.Products P
     ON P.productid = D.productid LEFT JOIN
     Production.Categories CA
     ON P.categoryid = CA.categoryid AND 
        CA.categoryname LIKE '%Confections%'
WHERE CA.CatgoryId IS NULL;
```

This version assumes that all orders have at least one product.  That seems like a reasonable assumption.  The query is easily adjusted for orders that have no products.

Comment: That's simply bright! I first thought 'No it can't work that way', and it's only because of the signature I gave it a second look... Probably the most efficient solution here.